# How should I make it so that if the user inputs something I don't want, it will trigger a message in C?

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I currently have this simple code that asks the user to enter a floating number, and with that value it would print it out, but I want to know how to make it so that it gives a message if user inputs anything, but a number. I know you need to use an if and else statement, but not sure what to use for the argument part..

My code so far(not done code yet until I find out how to handle inputs of non number):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float input;
    printf("Hello please enter a float number!\n";
    scanf( "%f", &input);
}
```

I know you need to use an if and else statement, but I come from a Python background so the syntax is completely different... Looking for some guidance as to how to handle this! Nothing too advanced please, I am looking for something simple.

Edit:

Thank you all of you guys for great replys! It really help me understand more of the different ways to handle such problems in future! :D

Comment: You check the return value of scanf. It should return 1 (for 1 item scanned), or there is problem.

Comment: It might be operating system specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that the input did input some number like `1.2` (and not something else like `!acd`) you should use the return value of `scanf` (it returns the number of scanned items).

Read the documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (and in general, read the documentation of every function that you are using):

> ```
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
> and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in 
> the event of an early matching failure.
> ```

```
 The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
 either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
```

Concretely you might code something like:

```
int main() {
   float input=0; // or perhaps NAN
   printf("Hello please enter a float number!\n";
   if (scanf( "%f", &input)<1) {
     perror("bad input"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

Of course, you might want to repeat the question till you get a floating point number. Then use a `while`. And you might handle differently invalid input (`scanf` returning 0) with end-of-file or error-on-read condition (`scanf` returning `EOF`), maybe:

```
int main() {
  float input=0;
  int nbscan= -1;
  do {
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    nbscan = scanf("%f", &input);
    if (nbscan==EOF) { perror("EOF from scanf"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  } while (nbscan<1);
  return 0;
 }
```

However, this usually means that the user did type some input; perhaps you want to catch the case when the user did not type anything within 500 milliseconds. Then, you should operating system specific functions or syscalls. On Linux and Posix, the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) syscall is relevant.

Comment: I understand what you mean by this, but the syntax I must write for this is not getting to me. So far I am thinking something like while(scanf()?

Comment: So, if input is not good, it will return a 0 as value and 1 if it is good.

Comment: And `scanf` returns `EOF` (on Linux that is -1) on end-of-file or read-error conditions.

Comment: I see..I will have to remember that since I am running windows right now and I only get to practice on linux at the computer labs at school. I might install linux later on if necessary..

Comment: Windows might have its own syscalls or functions to test that nothing was typed within 500ms. But I don't know Windows at all. And I do recommend installing Linux and studying the source code of free software.

Answer (score 3):

While doukremt is right in that you can check the return value of `scanf` to detect this particular error, `scanf` is really just for quick-and-dirty solutions, and has many failings when you want more robust behavior.

I would instead recommend reading a whole line of input as a string (using, for instance, `fgets`), and then using `strtof` or some similar function to convert it, which would tell you using its third argument when the conversion failed. Then you could check explicitly for every possible error condition and handle them appropriately.